# How to consume SOAP Siebel webservices in .net

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, siebel

Hi I am developing web application which contains Siebel web service integration. All request/response cycle will take place through XML. It is basically SOAP service. I do not have idea on siebel and soap xml. I am trying to integrate siebel service in WebAPi2. Client have provided me request and response and created sample service to test. I am able to invoke siebel service in fidler. In my webapi2 i want to integrate service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rol="Some Url">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rol:process>
         <rol:IDType>National Id</rol:IDType>
         <rol:Type>Customer</rol:Type>
         // other parametrs
      </rol:process>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <env:Header>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:some id</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:ReplyTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:FaultTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:FaultTo>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <processResponse xmlns="some url">
         <result>1-198A3H</result>
         <Contact_Integration_Id>1-198A3H</Contact_Integration_Id>
         <SIEBEL_ERROR_CODE/>
         <SIEBEL_ERRROR_MESSAGE/>
      </processResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>)
```

Also they have provided Public url to hit the API. 
As i do not know Siebel integration in .Net and i did not find any suitable tutorial I am expecting some help from here. Any help/suggestion i get here highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question has actually nothing to do with Siebel: you have a valid WSDL, and don't need to care if the web service is written in Siebel, Java, C# or whatever. You can forget about the Siebel part, and focus on how to integrate *any* WSDL in .Net - it should be easier to find documentation for that, I guess? Though I've never worked with .Net... :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @AJPerez is correct that this is not really a Siebel issue, I would like to recommend you request for the WSDL (Web Service Definition file) from which your example message is generated. Without it you'll find it hard to use the generic .NET tutorials regarding web services.

.NET has no doubt a generator that takes a WSDL as input and generates a set of classes and functions for you to use.